# Removing a CIFilter from a retreived asset

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, cifilter

In my app, the user selects an image that has been modified with a CIFilter from their camera roll with imagePicker. How do I get the original image / remove the CIFilter from that asset?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re doing this the right way from the start (using PHContentEditingOutput and PHAdjustmentData), then when you call `requestContentEditingInput` to perform another edit, the PHContentEditingInput provides the original image at `fullSizeImageURL`.